# bash - run .sh in loop

Tags: bash, loops, ssh

Hey i have loop and i need to run selected file but i dont have any idea how i can run sh file from different directory?

```
for f in "${FILES[@]}";
do
    if [[ $(basename $f) == *"$2" ]];
    then if [ -e "$f/run.sh" ]
         then echo "FOUND" && sh f/run.sh && break
         else echo "NOT FOUND"
         fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand `$f`:

```
then echo "FOUND" && sh "$f"/run.sh && break
```

Also depending on what `run.sh` does, you may want to use [source](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html), rather than running it in a new separate shell:

```
then echo "FOUND" && source "$f$"/run.sh && break
```

Comment: ok now, in this script is created "screen" with file located in different directory. but run.sh don't read this file and doesnt create new "screen". any idea how to run it ?

Comment: @user1366028 Is "$f" a directory? Maybe you want to `cd "$f" && source run.sh && cd ..`?

Comment: i have `&& cd "$f" && ls && source "$f/"run.sh` and i think script with "screen" is runing  but this doesn't found $server_name(varialbe with filename) inside this script